# Python: If Raw_Input Contains...BLAH

Tags: python, raw-input

(I am new to Python and programming) I am using `raw_input()` so I can make a program that talks to the user. For example:

Program: How are you?
User: I am doing great!/I feel terrible.

I need my program to respond accordingly, as in "YAY!" or "Aw man... I hope you feel better soon." so can you please give me ways to scan for words such as "good" or "bad" in the user's raw input so my program knows how to respond?

I know a few ways to do this, but the problem is, I want *multiple* words for it to look for, like great, amazing, and awesome can all be classified into the "good" group. AND, I need it where it doesn't have to be exact. I keep on running into problems where the user has to exactly type, "I am good." instead of all the different variations that they could possibly say it. THANK YOU IN ADVANCE!

Answer (score 2):

You might find `set`s useful here.

```
sentence = "I feel great"
words = sentence.split(" ")
if set("good", "fine", "great").intersects(words):
    print("user is good!")
if set("bad", "poorly", "sick").intersects(words):
    print("user is bad")
```

`set` is a special type of container, like a `list` or a `dict`.  It ignores repeated entries, but is extremely fast at checking whether an item already exists.  `set.intersects` returns a new `set` which contains only items found in both sides: so, in the first `if` statement above, it returns `set("great")`, which is "truthy" (behaves like `True` in a boolean context).  The second if statement gets an empty set, which is "falsey"

You could clean it up using a dictionary (but you have to make a slight modification I'll explain below)

```
responses = {frozenset("good", "fine", "great"): "that's fantastic",
             frozenset("bad", "poorly", "sick"): "I hope you feel better!"}

words = sentence.split(" ")
for wordset, reply in responses:
    if(wordset.intersects(words):
        print(reply)
```

The change we had to make us to use `frozenset` rather than `set`.  The only real difference that you need to worry about, is that a `frozenset` is *immutable*, which means you can't add or remove members from it.  For reasons relating to the implementation, `dict` keys *should* be immutable: you can't use `dict`, `list` or `set` as a key: but you can use `tuple`, `int`, `str` etc.

You could get exactly the same behaviour without using `set`: it just takes a couple more lines:

```
responses = {("good", "fine", "great"): "that's fantastic",
             ("bad", "poorly", "sick"): "I hope you feel better!"}

words = sentence.split(" ")
for wordtuple, reply in responses:
    for word in words:
        if word in wordtuple:
            print(reply)
            break
```

So, we need two more lines, and end up doing a lot more checking than we actually need to.  If there's a lot of possible words to check, that *can* slow your program down.  It isn't always bad to do it this way, for instance, you might get given `responses`, which means you won't have control over the types, but if you know you're writing all your own code, it's good to do things pythonically from the start.

Comment: I'd rather do it with simple `'x' in ['x','y','z']` instead of introducing different data types, to a new programmer, but good explanation nonetheless

Comment: @taesu I believe in teaching to do it *right*, not to do it easily.  And `set` is common (and useful) enough that it's a built in type.

Comment: Teaching easily is not necessary *wrong*. I am pretty sure new programmers will be overwhelmed with all these types you're throwing at them.

Comment: Thank you guys! :D

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not sure of having a program understand the english language. It will only take a string literal as a string literal. "Good" does not mean Good or Bad to the Interpreter in Python.

What I'd suggest is making a dictionary of all of the good phrases you want, such as I'm good, Feelin' great, I'm A OK. You can store all of these good feeling string literals to your "Good Feels" dictionary and vice versa for your Bad feels string literals.

I'm not too sure how you'd work around spelling with <100% accuracy and the interpreter still picking it up

I'm a bit inexperienced myself, but I'd say a predefined dictionary is your best bet, maybe throw in an else statement that prompts the user to spell correctly if he can't get one of the saying right.